# Calling method on back button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a navigation controller that has a hidden navigation bar on the first view, and then appears for all children views.  Problem is, I can't seem to hide it again if you go back to the first view.

I created a back button (so I could rename it) in the first view's init:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
  initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:nil target:self 
  action:@selector(hideNavigationBar:)];
```

But the method never gets called.  Why?

Comment: were you getting the title of the button as "Logout"

Comment: probably the navigation bar is getting hidden for the controller that you pop. So you press "logout", the bar is getting hidden, the controller is getting popped, you now see the previous controller , that is supposed to be without the bar, but the bar exists, isn't it?

Comment: The button is renamed correctly, just the method is never called.  I never see the log.

Answer (score 1):

In your first controller, in `-(void)viewWillAppear`, say:

```
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: +1. I do this as well, and it is a lot cleaner than editing the back button method.

Comment: Sure, @Devin Gund, and you can do it in any controller where you don't need the navBar, isn't it?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, just curious why I can't get the message from the back button working.